# Skipping the first line of file

Tags: awk

How to skip the first line to print columns in some format and after some arithmetic operation below? Is it possible with next?

Input

```
#filename
4e+06 5e+06 6e+06 
5e+06 5e+06 6e+06
```

Code:

```
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }
function t(n, s) {
s=index(n,".")
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+2) : n)
}
FR>1 {print t($1-1000),t($2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just made a typo in the last line of your awk script: It should read `FNR` instead of `FR` in the address:

```
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }

function t(n, s) {
   s=index(n,".")
   return (s ? substr(n,1,s+2) : n)
}

FNR>1 {print t($1-1000),t($2)}
```

This works here as expected.

With the typo, the address `FR>1` does not match any of your data lines: `FR` is a constant and the condition `FR>1` always false. That's why you do not get any output.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to skip the first line.

```
NR>1{ … }            # For every record after the first.
BEGIN{ getline }     # Only on the start, read the first line
!var{var=1;next}     # If var is unset, set it and skip one line.
FNR>1{ … }           # For records after the first for every file listed.
```

The variable `NR` means "Number of Record", and, assuming the default record delimiter (a newline) is in use, that is also the number of each line. The first line (in that case) is numbered `1`. If `NR` is greater than `1`, then what is executed inside the curly brace is executed only after the first line.

The variable `FNR`, instead, means the record number reset to zero for each file listed in the command line (`awk 'script' file1 file2 filen …`). Which is exactly equivalent to `NR>1` but gets reset for each new file.

## Trimming function

Additionally, you have a function definition for `t(n,s)` which aims (according to your comment) "to cut the number for 2 decimal places", but it doesn't do that correctly.

In that function definition there is a command that finds the dot. It is assuming the dot is the decimal separator:

```
s=index(n,".")
```

And then (as an string) cuts the string for the field two characters after the dot. That, for a number without exponent, works correctly to trim the decimals, but is the number is using an exponent, like `1.2345678e3`. It will be trimmed to `1.23`. That is, of course, not the same as the correct trimming to two decimals as `1234.56`.

To correctly trim the number, you must take the exponent into account. The `int` function does exactly that:

```
function ti(n){ return( int(100*n)/100 ) }
```

But you can better rely on the approximation that is applied to floats:

```
function tf(n){ return( sprintf( "%.2f",n ) ) }
```

They are different in the amount of approximation (actually, the type) each do. The function using int rounds toward zero to the lower integer (for a positive number). For a number like `3.7`, it rounds down to `3` anyway, the error is `0.7`. The function with float rounds to the nearest integer. The maximum error is `0.5`. A number as above, like `3.7`, rounds to `4`, the error is only `0.3`. So, one is a **round toward zero** approximation, the other is a **round to nearest integer**. One could have a max error of `0.9`, the other of only `0.5`. The only estrange thing about the float approximation is that it sometimes `0.5` rounds up and sometimes `0.5` rounds down. That is intended to balance rounds up with rounds down.

It is clear that 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and 0.4 should round down to 0.
That generates errors of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and 0.4.
Instead 0.9, 0.8. 0.7 and 0.6 round up to 1.
That generates error of -0.1, -0,2, -0.3, -0.4

All those errors (in average, for a random input) balance out.

But if we round 0.5 always up, it generates a constant error of 0.5.

To balance it out, once we round down, the next we round up.
Or, as it is usually written: **round ties (0.5) to even**.

```
printf '%s ' $l; echo; printf '%-3.0f ' $l; echo
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0 
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

Note that `0.5` rounds to `0` (down) and that `1.5` rounds to `2` (up)

## Precision

You should use `CONVFMT="%.16g"` as the format to convert floats.

An `f` format will trim off significant figures, like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{var=1.23456789e-8;printf "%.9f\n",var}'
0.000000012
```

Only two significant figures. Instead a `g` format:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{var=1.23456789e-8;printf "%.9f\n",var}'
1.23456789e-08
```

Will keep the 9 significant figures (digits).

## Filename

It is useful for awk commands that are applied to several files, like:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1{print $1}' file1 file2 file3
```

To use FNR instead of NR, so the condition apply to each file in turn.